# Updating value in jTextPane

Tags: java, radio-button, actionlistener, jtextpane, updating

I have a jTextPane set up and a panel with radioButtons. My jTextPane displays the contents of a text file I have chosen. The 3rd line, 4th index, displayed in my jTextPane specifies a value of type int. When I click my radioButton, I would like that value to increase by 1. So far, I have the following code. I tried to pane.setText(value + 1), but that doesn't seem to work. How do I update the value and display the updated value in jTextPane? My code,

```
private final ActionListener actionListen = new ActionListener() {
   for(String line: pane.getText().split("\\n")){
      String lineThree = line[3];
      int value =  lineThree.charAt(4);
      if(radioButton.isSelected()){
         pane.setText(value+1);
      }
   }
};
```

Comment: Do you have to use a `JTextPane`, cause `JList` would be easier...

Comment: Unfortunately, I am required to use JTextPane

Comment: I see 2 options : 1) Use an HTMLDocument and wrap your number with span tag. Then you can access that element with myHTMLDocument.getElement(spanID). 2) get the document and use commands to insert/remove into it